# Magento Cloud : Fixing Merge Conflict

Tags: magento2, git, magento2-cloud

I am working on a project based on Magento Commerce Cloud.

I am trying sync code from master to Staging branch but i am getting failure message.And when i view the logs,i am seeing merge conflict w.r.t some files.

Can anyone please guide on how can i fix this

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a way to fix this that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing where you are and what's awaiting change I can only suggest something like this:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard
git fetch
git rebase
git checkout master
git reset --hard
git fetch
git rebase
git merge develop
```

If you still get conflicts you will have to manually work through them after this point.

Others will probably suggest merging master into develop and resolving conflicts on develop branch.

But without seeing the files and what's happening it's a best guess scenario.

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine merge master in to staging and then use your tool of choice to manually fix the merge conflict, then push to Magento Cloud. PHP Storm is great for this.